# Scrape booking.com with Python against AJAX requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from booking.com and almost everything is working now but I am not able to get the prices, I read so far that it is because those prices are loaded via AJAX calls. Here is my code:

```
import requests
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.booking.com/searchresults.pl.html"
payload = {
'ss':'Warszawa', 
'si':'ai,co,ci,re,di',
'dest_type':'city',
'dest_id':'-534433',
'checkin_monthday':'25',
'checkin_year_month':'2015-10',
'checkout_monthday':'26',
'checkout_year_month':'2015-10',
'sb_travel_purpose':'leisure',
'src':'index',
'nflt':'',
'ss_raw':'',
'dcid':'4'
}

r = requests.post(url, payload)
html = r.content
parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

print parsed_html.head.find('title').text

tables = parsed_html.find_all("table", {"class" : "sr_item_legacy"})

print "Found %s records." % len(tables)

with open("requests_results.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(r.content)

for table in tables:
    name = table.find("a", {"class" : "hotel_name_link url"})
    average = table.find("span", {"class" : "average"})
    price = table.find("strong", {"class" : re.compile(r".*\bprice scarcity_color\b.*")})
    print name.text + " " + average.text + " " + price.text
```

Using `Developers Tools` from Chrome I noticed that the webpage sends a raw response with all of the data (including prices). After coping the response content from one of this tabs, there are raw values with prices, so why I can't retrieve them using my script, how to solve it?

[image]

Comment: check the headers sent, there might be something you don't mimic with your code

Comment: I have added all of the headers but the problem still exists.

Comment: Why not using selenium for this type of dynamic site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that the site is ill-formed: one `div` is opened in your table and an `em` is closed. So the `html.parser` cannot find the `strong` tag containing the price. This you can fix with installing and using `lxml`:

```
parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
```

The second problem is in your regex. It does not find anything. Change it to the following:

```
price = table.find("strong", {"class" : re.compile(r".*\bscarcity_color\b.*")})
```

Now you will find prices. However some entries do not contain any price thus your `print` statement will throw an error. To solve this you can change your `print` to the following:

```
print name.text, average.text, price.text if price else 'No price found'
```

And note that you can separate fields to print with comma (`,`) in Python so you do not need to concatenate them with `+ " " +`.

Comment: Wow, big thanks I've also noticed that this site is ill-formed (but I didn't know this term ;) ) and was trying to firstly use `prettify()` but that coused other strange errors, so your solution is excellent and suits me best.

Answer (score 0):

Booking.com has updated it's search endpoint, however we can still easily scrape it by manipulating URL parameters.

For example, if we type our search query here:

[image]

We can see a complex GET request being made in our Network Inspector. However it's much more simple than it appears - we can easily replicate it in Python:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from httpx import AsyncClient
from parsel import Selector

def parse_search_page(html: str):
    """parse hotel preview data from search page HTML"""
    sel = Selector(text=html)

    hotel_previews = {}
    for hotel_box in sel.xpath('//div[@data-testid="property-card"]'):
        url = hotel_box.xpath('.//h3/a[@data-testid="title-link"]/@href').get("").split("?")[0]
        hotel_previews[url] = {
            "name": hotel_box.xpath('.//h3/a[@data-testid="title-link"]/div/text()').get(""),
            "location": hotel_box.xpath('.//span[@data-testid="address"]/text()').get(""),
            "score": hotel_box.xpath('.//div[@data-testid="review-score"]/div/text()').get(""),
            "review_count": hotel_box.xpath('.//div[@data-testid="review-score"]/div[2]/div[2]/text()').get(""),
            "stars": len(hotel_box.xpath('.//div[@data-testid="rating-stars"]/span').getall()),
            "image": hotel_box.xpath('.//img[@data-testid="image"]/@src').get(),
        }
    return hotel_previews


async def search_page(
    query,
    session: AsyncClient,
    checkin: str = "",
    checkout: str = "",
    number_of_rooms=1,
    offset: int = 0,
):
    """scrapes a single hotel search page of booking.com"""
    checkin_year, checking_month, checking_day = checkin.split("-") if checkin else "", "", ""
    checkout_year, checkout_month, checkout_day = checkout.split("-") if checkout else "", "", ""

    url = "https://www.booking.com/searchresults.html"
    url += "?" + urlencode(
        {
            "ss": query,
            "checkin_year": checkin_year,
            "checkin_month": checking_month,
            "checkin_monthday": checking_day,
            "checkout_year": checkout_year,
            "checkout_month": checkout_month,
            "checkout_monthday": checkout_day,
            "no_rooms": number_of_rooms,
            "offset": offset,
        }
    )
    return await session.get(url, follow_redirects=True)

# Example use:
# first we need to immitate web browser headers to not get blocked instantly
HEADERS = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,lt;q=0.8,et;q=0.7,de;q=0.6",
}


async def run():
    async with AsyncClient(headers=HEADERS) as session:
        # For example, lets search for hotels in London:
        response = await search_page("London", session)
        results = parse_search_page(response.text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(run())
```

The above example uses `httpx` and `parsel` community libraries to scrape booking.com hotel search results.
I write more on scraping booking.com in my blog [How to Scrape Booking.com](https://scrapfly.io/blog/how-to-scrape-bookingcom/#scraping-search)